# getting POST <my_url> 500 (OK), when using $.ajax POST to send json to django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-csrf

Edite: refined the code according to advice in comments but still no luck

Update: thanks ThiefMaster after following your advice I found a bug in my view function but after fixing it now I get in django debug

> Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Help Reason given for
>   failure:
>       CSRF token missing or incorrect.
>
> ---

I trying to use jquery ajax to send json data to django

here is my js code

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    console.log(events);
    var filter = [];
    filter[0] = 'start';
    filter[1] = 'end';
    filter[2] = 'title';
    events = JSON.stringify(events, filter, '\t');
    console.log(events);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {events: events},
        url: <my_url>,
    });
});
```

on chrome devtool every thing is ok until the last $.ajax()

it throw this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)

If any one can figure out what I'm doing wrong please go ahead

thanks in advance

Comment: That's an error from your server.  Check your server logs or whatever.

Comment: Fyi, the better way to create an array is `[]` instead of `new Array()` (same with objects, it's `{}` instead of `new Object()` there)

Comment: You should also make your variables local using `var`; the code doesn't look like it needs `events` to be global.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using localserver for development

Comment: @ThiefMaster edited the code and no luck

Comment: See my answer. If that doesn't help you need to check the output from the django dev server to see what's going wrong and update your question (in that case it's probably not related to your JS but something going wrong due to an issue with your server-side code)

Comment: thanks for helping @ThiefMaster and sorry if this is ediot question but how can I get the django output if I'm using ajax, so I can't see the debug output

Comment: Firebug for example - but doesn't the django dev server dump exceptions and tracebacks on the console, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data: "events"` should be `data: events`. Your server might not like a non-json payload.

You also want to add `contentType: 'application/json'` since you want to post json, not form-encoded values. If you *do* expect form-encoded values on the server-side though, use `data: {events: events}` to get a POST data field `events` containing the JSON string.

Comment: Edited the code and still not working and worth to mention I'm developing on my local ubuntu machine

Comment: thanks for help, your advice about checking the django output solved part of the problem, I found error in my view causing the 500 page, but now I'm gitteng 403 error with this msg

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other part of the solution about Forbidden 403 regarding csrf

in this page of Django docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax